# Why are civic duties part of Competence (C1) in the NEO-PI-R

Tags: test, consciousness, big-five

In the [Revised NEO Personality Inventory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revised_NEO_Personality_Inventory), one of the questions used to score C1 ("Competence"), is `35. I don't take civic duties like voting very seriously.`

Why is civic duty part used to measure a person's Competence? I can see how it fits under the broader label conscientiousness (C), but I fail to see its relevance for (C1) Competence. I would have expected it to count towards (C3) Dutifulness.